Remote Deskop "Access is Denied" but only if the user is not already logged in locally
I am using RDP to connect to a Windows 11 Pro 23H2 from a windows 10 machine. If I am already logged on locally to the Windows 11 box, RDP works normally, kicking off the local user and letting the remote user in.
If the user account is not already logged in (first login after boot or after a timeout) RDP just says "Access is Denied" with no info. Event viewer shows a successful login.
I have tried everything I can find online with no luck. I can't get any log to show anything being wrong, it's just RDP can't seem to activation the session unless it had already been logged in.
This question suggests disabling NLA and storing the user credential locally, but it is insecure:
"Your Credentials Did Not Work" unless logged in locally first
Which confuses me...my win10 box forces NLA and I can connect to it just fine on the first attempt.
The Win11 box has NLA Turned off and I still can't connect to it.
So Win10 works with NLA (or without) but Win11 doesn't work with NLA or without. ??
Same behavior with Domain accounts and local...user is Administrator and a member of the Remote Desktop Users group.
Goal here is to use NLA (like on the win10 box) and allow first connections.
Any ideas?
